# Error 2878 at SQLLogin dialog in Installshield 2010

Tags: installation, installshield-2010

I am using MSI project with Installshield 2010.

I wanted to add some SQL Scripts in my project for two different connections. I was trying to clone SQLLogin dialog and configure it for the second connection, I don't know exactly what I did, I exported, imported, deleted, cloned this dialog for many times to experiment some stuff and now, when I test the setup (is not a build error) I get this error:

> Error 2878: On the dialog SQLLogin the control RadioButtonGroup1 has a possible value: 0. This is an invalid or duplicate value.

The error appears just before SQLLogin dialog.

After others experiments to fix this error, I deleted the SQLLogin dialog and all my SQL connections to start all over again (I have noticed that SQLLogin dialog is not disponible in a Basic MSI project if a SQL Connection is not setted, the dialog appears in the list after a new Sql Connection is made) and I added a new SQL Connection (I have not made any changes in Sql Connection) and as I supposed, the SQLLogin dialog was generated.

I build the project and run it and the error still occurs.. I don't know how to fix it, if I set a new sql connection to another project all works fine, this is a bug specific for my project.

A bad solution is to start the project again because is a biiiig one..

Any ideas how to fix this error? Maybe I deleted some important variables? Or some actions?!

Any idea is welcome, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all operation I have made with the dialogs, the property of RadioButtonGroup1 called IS_SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATION appears many times in the tables of msi configuration (see Additional Tools tab, Direct Editor -> here you can find all tables of msi).

I delete the duplicated properties, build and run the setup again.

Thanks for help Gabriel!